# Extracting information out of a column with regexs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

Is it possible to get the (first?) match of a regex and output it within a select? It looks like the `REGEXP` function only return whether there has been a match or not. I want to be able to extract information out of a varchar column without having to use complex SUBSTRING-LOCATION nestings.

Any ideas?

Comment: In this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826 , @Jeremy Stein suggested using User-defined functions: https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html that's all there is. You can't do more than pattern comparison.